Which manuscripts contain 'It is hard for you to kick against the goads' in Acts 9:5?
The KJV and NKJV appear to be the only English translations that include the sentence 'It is hard for you to kick against the goads.' at the end of Acts 9:5. When I look at an interlinear for this verse, I see that this part is surrounded by curly brackets:

{ σκληρόν σοι πρὸς κέντρα λακτίζειν }

Does this mean that this part is not present in some original manuscripts? If so, which ones do contain this part?

The expression is present in Stephanus (1550) κληρόν σοι πρὸς κέντρα λακτίζειν and in Beza (1598). It is also present in Tyndale (1534) And in the Wycliffe bible (1382). Up-voted +1.

The Greek text of Acts 9:5 is

εἶπεν δέ Τίς εἶ, Κύριε; ὁ δέ Ἐγώ εἰμι Ἰησοῦς ὃν σὺ διώκεις· = And he
said, "Who are You, Lord?" And He said, "I am Jesus, whom you are
persecuting.

This text is the same in UBS5/NA28, Byzantine text, W&H, Souter, NIVGNT, Orthodox Church text, Majority text, THGNT, SBL, etc, etc.
The KJV (& NKJV) are alone in adding "It is hard for you to kick against the goads.”".  In this respect, the addition accords with the Clementine Vulgate text of 1592 used for the Douay-Rheims Bible. (It is absent in Jerome's Vulgate of 400 AD.)
Now, most references like USB5 and NA28 list the MSS that support disputed readings, but none are listed for this verse because it is undisputed except for the KJV and its associated Textus Receptus.  In creating the Textus Receptus via his "Novvm Instrumentum Omne" publication, Erasmus used the following Greek MSS for Acts:

Codex Basilensis A. N. IV. 2, dated to the 12th century
Codex Basilensis A. N. IV. 4, dated to the 12th century
Codex Basilensis A. N. IV. 5, dated to the 15th century

That is, all were relatively recent to Erasmus' effort in 1516.  However, I cannot confirm which of these documents contained the text in question.
